# An image with proper permissions and correctly linked disappeared from my site

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website.

http://olympiandiamonds.worldwidejamie.com

As I was building the site and uploading files, the site logo suddenly stopped displaying. I don't get any errors in the console as if it's not finding the image or suggesting there might be a permission error.

The image just isn't displaying.

Here is my code:

```
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bottomNav">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/Olympian_Faceted.png" alt="Olympian Logo" /></a>
            </div>
```

It's a pretty straightforward bootstrap site and any of the topics I've found are mentioning a path being wrong or the image not being uploaded to the server. I've checked both of those and I can't seem to solve why the image won't display.

Comment: Something is wrong with your image. Recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check at least following things

1. You are using `img/Olympian_Faceted.png` as source. Is it same name on servers?
2. Try renaming the file
3. Try JPEG instead of PNG

Because, image is not showing if I open it in browser http://olympiandiamonds.worldwidejamie.com/img/Olympian_Faceted.png

Comment: I tried to rename the file and that didn't work. Then I resaved and renamed it as .jpg. That's what got it to work. I'm still very curious as to why the image wasn't showing up as on the server nor was it showing up as not found.